# jQuery Select Length - Unable to get an accurate count

Tags: jquery

I have a Select that looks as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" id="UserList" name="UserList"><option value="1214">Cindy Doe</option>
<option value="1210">Demo</option>
<option value="1213">Jane Doe</option>
<option value="1212">John Doe</option>
<option value="1215">Mark Doe</option>
<option value="1216">Tommy Doe</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">-- Select User --</option>
</select>
```

When I attempt to get the number of items in the Select as follows, it always returns 1 instead of 7.

```
alert($("#UserList").length);
```

There must be something simple here I'm overlooking.

Comment: Your selector is targeting the `<select>` input and taking its length, not the length of the `<option>`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is counting the number of elements with the id of `UserList` - which should only ever return `0` or `1` as id attributes should be unique within a page.

To achieve what you want, you need to count the number of `option` elements within the `select`:

```
alert($("#UserList option").length);
```

Comment: @DavidThomas well, yes. I'll amend for clarity :)